# Flutter - Keep track of data between screens

Tags: flutter, local-storage

I'm trying to make a Gym app. You can add a workout by pressing the + on the appbar, and this takes you to a new screen where you can add the information about all the exercises and the workout name. When you press the check button, it goes back to the main screen where it displays all the workout that you've created, so that if you tap on a list tile it displays all the exercises.

My problem is that I don't know how to pass all the information about the exercises back to the main page. The only thing that I pass back is the workout name. My idea was to pass a Map<String workoutName, List> so that in the main page I have everything that I need. What do you think about it?
P.S. Rn I'm not storing anything in LocalStorage yet, mainly because I don't know what to store I was thinking about storing the Map<String workoutName, List> But I'm a fresh dev on Flutter so there may be easier solutions.
[image: This is the main page]
[image: This is the workoutCreation page]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. Because of the inevitable growth of your requirements, I suggest going with the most common way to both pass variables and control your state.  Meaning:  when your variables change, when you return to your original screen, the screen also rebuilds to show your new information.  [Riverpod](https://pub.dev/packages/riverpod) has become the successor to the previously Flutter team recommended State Management solution.

I suggest finding a nice, popular tutorial on Riverpod, perhaps building an app entirely with the video to give yourself a good start.